# Add new field with the name based on another field

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I would like to know how can I add a new field in an attribute table with a name based on the value of another field.  I mean, if I had a field with values 1,2,3 and 4, I need to add four new fields like A1, A2, A3 and A4 (A is aleatory, only for giving a name to new field).  I did it in ModelBuilder but I would like to do the same in a script for python.

Can anyone help me with this task?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.1 and Python 2.7.5